# How to transform a stochastic jump diffusion equation to a Levy stochastic differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If I have this type of stochastic differential equation :
$$
dX(t) = A(X(t),t)\ dt +B(X(t),t)\ dW(t) + C(X(t),t)\ dP(t)
$$
With 
$$
\begin{align}
dW(t)& : \text{A wiener process}\\
dP(t)& : \text{A Poisson process with parameter }\Lambda\\
A,B,C& : \text{Smooth functions}
\end{align}
$$
and I want to transform it to this type of stochastic differential equations:
$$
dX(t) = F(X(t),t)\ dt + G(X(t),t)\ dL(t)\\
$$
with
$$
\begin{align}
L(t)&  : \text{An }\alpha\text{-stable Levy process}
\end{align}
$$
I was trying to identify the relations between the coefficients and parameters. Could some one tell me if I can use the development of a Levy process to a Brownian motion, a drift and a poisson process to find a relation between those two equations ?

I wanted to use it in the case $F$ and $G$ are constants.

Thank you.

Kind regards

Comment: @ Samatix : When possible I think that the best way to do it is to use Lévy-Khintchine decomposition of the process and identifying terms. Best regards

Comment: Hi TheBridge. I found the equation using google but it is too complicated to apply. Could you, please, write down the Lévy-Khintchine formula ?
Best regards

Comment: Do you know where I can find the formula you talked about ?